# How to get values from dictionaries recursively using Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key

I'm working with some complex JSON files, and I need to read all the values and rename them when they meet a certain string.

The problem is the JSON file contains dictionaries inside lists inside dictionaries... very crazy. This is an example:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "subkey11": "KeepMe1",
        "subkey12": "ChangeMe2"
    },
    "key2": [],
    "key3": [],
    "key4": [
        {
            "subkey41": "ChangeMe41",
            "subkey42": "KeepMe42",
            "subkey43": "ChangeMe43",
            "subkey44": [
                {
                    "subkey441": "ChangeMe441",
                    "subkey442": "KeepMe442"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How could I read everything recursively to get the values and rename them if it's needed?

I'm getting completely crazy with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain more in detail what you have tried so far. SO is not a code-writing service, but we will be glad to help if you can show us where you went wrong.

Comment: @PaxVobiscum It's difficult to explain everything I have tried. I'm not trying to get the answer by the easy way, I'm just asking for some tips that help me to know different points of view and apply the solution that I consider it's the best. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be easier if you convert the json string in to python dict object like this.

```
import json

data = """
{
    "key1": {
        "subkey11": "KeepMe1",
        "subkey12": "ChangeMe2"
    },
    "key2": [],
    "key3": [],
    "key4": [
        {
            "subkey41": "ChangeMe41",
            "subkey42": "KeepMe42",
            "subkey43": "ChangeMe43",
            "subkey44": [
                {
                    "subkey441": "ChangeMe441",
                    "subkey442": "KeepMe442"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
"""
print json.loads(data)
```

output:-

```
{u'key3': [], u'key2': [], u'key1': {u'subkey11': u'KeepMe1', u'subkey12': u'ChangeMe2'}, u'key4': [{u'subkey44': [{u'subkey441': u'ChangeMe441', u'subkey442': u'KeepMe442'}], u'subkey43': u'ChangeMe43', u'subkey42': u'KeepMe42', u'subkey41': u'ChangeMe41'}]}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to read the keys recursively, but this is easier.